# Why won't my UITableView segue to a detail view?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I wanted to have a tab bar controller, then a table view controller with a corresponding detail view.  I am new to this, so I tried combining Apple's SimpleDrillDown:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html

...with Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on Storyboards:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Ray's shows you how to set up the tabs and get the first table view, but then doesn't show you how to get a detail view, so then I tried to learn how to get the detail view from Apple's SimpleDrillDown (which doesn't have the tab bar controller).

My program runs with no errors, but when you click on a row in the table view (FactSheetsViewController), it stays blue (selected) and never segues to my FactSheetsDetailViewController.  If I put a breakpoint in my table view class at this method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DisplaySelectedFactSheet"]) {   
        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        FactSheetsDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.factSheet = [dataController objectInListAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];     
    }
}
```

The breakpoint is never reached when I run the program and click on a cell.

I'm not sure what other code to post, because I'm not sure what I did wrong.  I'm wondering if I initialized things incorrectly in my AppDelegate?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];   
    FactSheetsViewController *factSheetsViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];   
    DataController *controller = [[DataController alloc] init];
    factSheetsViewController.dataController = controller;
    self.dataController = controller;

    return YES;
 }
```

Or, if I'm not setting things up correctly in the storyboard somehow.  I set the identifier to my segue from FactSheetsViewController to my FactSheetsDetailView to "DisplaySelectedFactSheet" in the attributes inspector.

I'm happy to post more details if it would help - please just let me know!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode, you need to create a segue between the **table cell** (prototype) and the `FactSheetsDetailViewController`.  Then, also in Xcode, edit the segue name to be `DisplaySelectedFactSheet`.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  I was trying to begin the segue at the ViewController, not the actual cell.  This fixed it!